# AJAX in WP Plugin returns 0 always

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to implement WP AJAX in one of my [Under-dev Plugin](https://github.com/nanodesigns/ad-zonia/blob/master/ad-view-page.php) after successful implementation in WP Theme.

```
function deactivate_ad() {

    if( isset( $_POST['id'] ) ) {
        echo $_POST['id'];
        echo 'Deactivated';
        die;
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, not done';
        die;
    }
    wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}

add_action('wp_ajax_deactivate_ad', 'deactivate_ad');
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_deactivate_ad', 'deactivate_ad'); //not logged in users
```

And beneath the function somewhere, I added my form with dynamic ID:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
          <script type="text/javascript">
          var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

          jQuery(document).on('click', '.deactivate-ad', function () {
              var id = this.id;
              alert(id);
              jQuery.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: ajaxurl,
                  data: {
                    "action": "deactivate_ad",
                    "id": id
                  },
                  success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                  }
              });
          });
        </script>
<?php
        //after the db Query, within the foreach loop
        foreach( $ad_query as $the_ad ){
            $element_id = 'deactivate_' . $the_ad->id . '_' . wp_create_nonce('deactivate_' . $the_ad->id );
            // I'm just checking with the 'Deactivate' button first
            echo ( $the_ad->ad_status == 1 ? '<a class="deactivate-ad" href="#" id="'. $element_id .'">Deactivate</a>' : '<a href="?page=site-ad&id='. $the_ad->id .'&activate=true&success=true">Activate</a>' );
        }
?>
</form>
```

I'm just trying to activate the AJAX so that I can do whatever I want then. But with first `alert(id)` I can alert the `id` with nonce successfully, but the `alert(data)` it's always returning `0` (zero).

I am enqueueing  the latest jQuery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) at the beginning and checked all the instances. What am I doing wrong this time - the process I acquired worked in a theme - I worked earlier.

Comment: Do you get the AJAX options in the PHP function with `print_r['$_POST'];` ?

Comment: I'm afraid where to post this? I added the print_r within my function, and it's returning syntax error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['...` :(

Comment: Could you paste the whole error in a pastebin? I don't see a syntax error in your code above, you also did everything right for using AJAX with Wordpress. Oh, wait I do! Try data keys without "" -> action: "deactivate_ad", ...

Comment: I tried `data: { "action": deactivate_ad, "id": id }` and it's not firing AJAX. I then tried `"action": 'deactivate_ad'`, it's behaving as expected like double quote, returning zero (0) as usual.

Comment: You don't need `die;` under each conditional. `wp_die();` at the end of your function is sufficient.

Comment: Also, you don't need to define `ajaxurl`, as it says in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins): "_since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should re-place the following code from `adzonia-view.php` to `wp-adzonia.php`

```
function deactivate_ad() {

if( isset( $_POST['id'] ) ) { echo $_POST['id']; echo 'Deactivated';

} else { echo 'Sorry, not done';

} die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_deactivate_ad', 'deactivate_ad');
```

**Reason:**
Because you wrote the functions in a menu page. It's already hooked in with may be `admin_menu` hook. So it's too late to add actions in `wp_ajax_*`.

Comment: You honestly just saved me, i've been trying to figure this out for hours! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try: `data: { action: "deactivate_ad", id: id }` - seems like a typo!

Edit: Ok I implemented it like this:

page-xy.php:

```
<div class="deactivate-ad">Jup</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

        jQuery(document).on('click', '.deactivate-ad', function () {
            var id = 5;
            console.log(id);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: "deactivate_ad",
                    id: id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

function.php:

```
function deactivate_ad() {


    if( isset( $_POST['id'] ) ) {
        echo $_POST['id'];
        echo 'Deactivated';
        die;
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, not done';
        die;
    }
    wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}

add_action('wp_ajax_deactivate_ad', 'deactivate_ad');
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_deactivate_ad', 'deactivate_ad'); //not logged in users
```

And the alert output is: 5Deactivated

Meaning, I don't think AJAX is your problem here. Unfortunatly I can't test the other code since it's insufficient!