# Wordpress plugin ajax returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to send AJAX data to my **wordpress** table but all I can get from my PHP is a `0`. Its on the admin side. Can anyone help me?

Also all of this code is inside my `plugin-admin.php` file inside my plugin folder.

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) exit;

    global $wpdb;
    global $wp_version;


  $results = $wpdb -> get_results(
              "
                SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE post_type =  'post' and post_status NOT LIKE 'auto-draft'
                AND post_title NOT LIKE 'Auto Draft'
                AND post_status = 'publish'
                ORDER BY post_title
              "
            );

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_featured_submit_action', 'featured_submit_callback' );

  function featured_submit_callback(){
    echo "hi";

    wp_die();
  }



?>

<div class="wrap">
  <h2>Select Posts</h2>
    <select id="selected-posts" multiple="multiple">
      <?php
        foreach ( $results as $result ){
          ?><option value="<?php echo $result->ID; ?>"> <?php echo $result->post_title; ?> </option> <?php
        }
      ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="sposts-submit"></input>


</div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var spostsarray = new Array();

    //Click button
    $("#sposts-submit").click(function(){

      var spostsarray = new Array();

      $("#selected-posts").each(function(item){
        spostsarray.push( $(this).val() );
      });
      console.log(spostsarray);

      var data = {
        "action": "featured_submit_action",
        "posts": spostsarray
      }

      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        type: "POST",
        action: "featured_submit_action",
        data: {"posts": spostsarray},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      });

    });


  });
</script>
```

I've condensed it a bit but the general idea is that I can grab all the recent posts and the user can select which ones they want to feature, send that to the PHP method and edit the table with it.

The problem is with my AJAX callback I only ever return `0` and not the data sent from the javascript.

SOLVED:
After some help from Rohil_PHPBeginner I figured it out.  The reason it didn't work is that I was executing the code from the menu page at at that point it was too late to add a hook.  Here is the page I used to solve it:

[AJAX in WP Plugin returns 0 always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23696577/ajax-in-wp-plugin-returns-0-always)

Comment: Have you debugged in the browser?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find whats wrong.

Comment: You should be able to see the request and response, does everything look right? Have you ran your query outside the program?

Comment: I have, if by query you mean my SQL code then yes the sql works perfect.  Its just my ajax that isn't.

Comment: please add add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_featured_submit_callback', 'featured_submit_callback' );

Comment: my comment is similar to following answer...and also 1 min earlier

Comment: @vrajesh **Its on the admin side.** I think you have missed that line. So I don't think by adding `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_featured_submit_callback', 'featured_submit_callback' ); ` will make any difference.

Comment: @vrajesh But your comment is wrong. `nopriv` is used for callbacks for logged out users. When you don't want your callback to be called for logged out users you don't need it (as in the OP's case). The actual reason why the code doesn't work is failure to pass the action param to the AJAX function rendering WordPress unable to match the ajax call to a registered ajax callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked perfectly fine for me:

```
<?php
        global $wpdb;
        global $wp_version;


      $results = $wpdb -> get_results(
                  "
                    SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt
                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                    WHERE post_type =  'post' and post_status NOT LIKE 'auto-draft'
                    AND post_title NOT LIKE 'Auto Draft'
                    AND post_status = 'publish'
                    ORDER BY post_title
                  "
                );
    ?>

    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>Select Posts</h2>
        <select id="selected-posts" multiple="multiple">
          <?php
            foreach ( $results as $result ){
              ?><option value="<?php echo $result->ID; ?>"> <?php echo $result->post_title; ?> </option> <?php
            }
          ?>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="sposts-submit"></input>
    </div>

<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_featured_submit_action', 'featured_submit_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_featured_submit_action', 'featured_submit_callback' );

function featured_submit_callback(){
   echo "hi";
   wp_die();
}
?>

    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //Click button
        $("#sposts-submit").click(function(){

          var spostsarray = new Array();

          $("#selected-posts").each(function(item){
            spostsarray.push( $(this).val() );
          });
          console.log(spostsarray);

          var data = {
            "action": "featured_submit_action",
            "posts": spostsarray
          }

          $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
```

You don't need to pass the AJAX url in that way because when I used your code, it is showing me with PHP. WordPress provides a default url for AJAX so you can use that( `ajaxurl` which I used in below code).

Other than that You have not added code for `no-privilege` user (if it is going to use only for privileged user then it is okay otherwise you need to add code for that).

Comment: I just tried with your code and still seem to be getting a response of 0

Comment: Is the problem that they are all in the same file?

Comment: I figured it out, it was to late to hook actions, your answer helped me get there.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress returns 0 when an ajax call doesn't find a valid callback function (though the 0 could be return from many other things).

WordPress looks for callbacks matching `wp_ajax_{callback}` when a user is logged in and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{callback}` when the user is logged out. {callback} is populated with the POST'd value of the "action" hidden input. Note that you're not passing the `action` into your AJAX call. You should change:
`data: {"posts": spostsarray},`
to 
`data: data`

Since you're not going to match a callback function without passing in action, WordPress is returning 0

Comment: Also `SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type =  'post' and post_status NOT LIKE 'auto-draft' AND post_title NOT LIKE 'Auto Draft' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title`  could be simplified to SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type =  'post' and post_title NOT LIKE 'Auto Draft' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_title`. Also, limit/paginate your queries. That will kill a server with 1k+ posts. Further you should really use WP_Query to take advantage of WP's inbuilt SQL caching instead of direct SQL